# Large Array - Out of Memory Error

Tags: java, android, arrays, out-of-memory, ram

I am writing an Android application for a single specific phone (which just needs to run on my personal phone) and I need to make use of the following large array, which I want to use to efficiently convert RGB colors to HSV:

`RainbowTable = new float[256*256*266][3];`

The total size of this array should be 256*256*256*3*4B = 201326592B = 192MB.
When I debug the app, I get an `out of memory exception`, although approximately 300MB RAM are still free before its execution, according to the Android task manager.

I have already set the `large-heap`-option to `true` in the manifest file.

What can I do to prevent this error and preserve the needed amount of RAM?

EDIT: My phone is rooted, so maybe there is a possibility to increase the size of the memory heap per application.

Comment: That seems like A LOT of memory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each device has a maximum per-app RAM cap.  If this call in the manifest does not alleviate your problem:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Then your only other option is to write your code using the NDK.  But that's a pretty hefty thing to dive into, so I would try to figure out an alternative first.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum heap size is device dependent and 192MB is likely to be over the limit allowed by devices at the moment.

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11275719/1517648) indicates that you can use the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to allocate more memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you already tried this **largeHeap=true**, I doubt there is a working solution, normally the size of a single memory heap can be maximal 24 - 48 mb depending on the device

Comment: I have already stated in my question that I have set it to true, but thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ByteBuffer

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( bigSize);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me neither. Using a byte buffer I receive an out-of-memory-exception again.

Answer (score -2):

yes this memory issue happens when app uses large memory. 
do call System.gc(); this will clear the garbage collector explicitly.
Every app in android uses the limited ammount of memory its about 16mb.
so try this.

Comment: GC will do nothing since the object is referenced.