# Out Of Memory String Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am receiving huge JSON and and while I am reading the lines OutOfMemoryError appears.

Here is my first method that I am trying to parse the JSON.

```
    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), 8);
    String result = "";

    while (true) {

                String ss = reader.readLine();
                if (ss == null) {
                        break;
                }
                result += ss;
   }
```

And I've also tried this method.

```
    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
    sb.append(line);
    }
```

In the both of the cases the OutOfMemoryErorr is appearing.

Comment: Did you try using the android standard solution for parsing JSON files? http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html, also have a look at JsonReader: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Comment: What is the size of incoming data?

Comment: It's around 10mb per Object and in the JSON are more than 20 Objects, it's 10mb cause I am getting base64..

Comment: And I've tried the Standard JSON parsers but they are not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I found was to raise the Heap of the Application.

I placed `android:largeHeap="true"` under the `<application/>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: `android:largeHeap=true` is not the recommended solution: [https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#YourApp](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#YourApp)

Comment: @KenTan the answer is from 2013, now it's 2016 :)

Answer (score 3):

Mostly the error will occur due to heap size. You need to increase the size of the heap

[To increase the heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application)

For additional info on heap size in java visit [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#nonstandard)

Comment: this is wrong. he wont be able to change heap size on a real device. And I'm not sure that -Xmx2048m option will change anything in android.

Comment: I can't find the "Arguments" option in Run Configurations. I am using Android Development Tools (Eclipse).

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate your `BufferedReader`, you pass in an `int size` of `8`, meaning your buffer is 8 characters (I assume that's not what you want). If you pass no `size`, the default is 8192 characters.

Try this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

Or this (same effect):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), 8192);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html

I'm not completely sure that will fix the error you are seeing, but worth trying if you can't get it working.

Comment: I am using BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), 8192); and there is still Out Of Memory.

Comment: Hmm... I'm reading above you saying that you have 20 objects at 10MB a piece? If that's the case, that's a payload of 200MB that you are trying to hold in memory (hence OOM errors). Even 10MB is a huge payload for JSON, as many devices have an app heap size around 20-30MB. You may want to look into chunking your download or breaking up the JSON that the service is returning.

Comment: I was hoping that would be the worst case scenario, but it seems that is the only way. Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 1):

My JSON code was waiting for status, which comes towards the end. So I modified the code to return earlier.

```
// try to get formattedAddress without reading the entire JSON
        String formattedAddress;
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            formattedAddress = ((String) ((JSONObject) new JSONObject(
                    jsonResults.toString()).getJSONArray("results").get(0))
                    .get("formatted_address"));
            if (formattedAddress != null) {
                Log.i("Taxeeta", "Saved memory, returned early from json") ;
                return formattedAddress;
            }               
        }
JSONObject statusObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        String status = (String) (statusObj.optString("status"));
        if (status.toLowerCase().equals("ok")) {
            formattedAddress = ((String) ((JSONObject) new JSONObject(
                    jsonResults.toString()).getJSONArray("results").get(0))
                    .get("formatted_address"));
            if (formattedAddress != null) {
                Log.w("Taxeeta", "Did not saved memory, returned late from json") ;
                return formattedAddress;
            }           
        }
```