# Getting out of memory error while passing byte array of size 5 mb to web service using ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I have converted my DB file to byte array and want to pass it my web service in order to save on server. My db is 5 mb in size but while adding to soap_request it's giving out of memory exception....I am attaching my code as below

```
File file = new File(filePath);
                int size = (int) file.length();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

                Log.v(TAG, "File size in byte ==>"+size);
                try {
                    BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                    buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    buf.close();
                    Log.v(TAG, "ByteArray = "+bytes.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    SoapObject soap_request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    fileName = "TraceBaleAndroid_"+UserID+"_"+backupDateTime+".db";
                    Log.v(TAG, "FileName = "+fileName);
                    soap_request.addProperty("_FileName", fileName);

                    soap_request.addProperty("_ByteArray",bytes);
                    soap_request.addProperty("UserID", UserID);

                    Log.v(TAG, "soap_request _FileName= >>"+soap_request.getProperty(0));
                    //Log.v(TAG, "soap_request _ByteArray= >>"+soap_request.getProperty(1));
                    Log.v(TAG, "soap_request UserID= >>"+soap_request.getProperty(2));

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap_request);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;

                    Log.v(TAG,"Calling webservice....");
                    androidHttpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    androidHttpTransportSE.debug = true;
                    androidHttpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                    Log.v(TAG,"Getting result from webservice....");
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                    Log.v(TAG, "Web Response...." + response.get(" Result "));

                    if (response.get(" Result ").equals("Uploading DataBase Backup To Server successfully"))
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        Log.v(TAG, "Database is uploaded .........");
                    }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally 
            {
                androidHttpTransportSE.reset();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

SOAP request with 5MB data looks really odd to me. But if you are really sure you need this, check answers to this question: [How to increase heap size of an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application)
All those advices are valid for your case too.

Comment: I will try this and also if you know any other way to send this byte array to web service please suggest me as I am fresher and haven't did much in this area....thanks in advance

Comment: Actually my byte array is of size 5345280 but getting error like "Out of memory on a 16035856-byte allocation." and that android:largeHeap =  true is not working in my case...

Comment: i ususally don't use KSOAP instead HTTPGET or POST

Comment: @Narendra, use HTTP POST as Ashish Jani suggests above.

Comment: @AndreyVoitenkov how to call particular web service method using HTTP POST as we can call particular method using KSOAP please if possible modify my code accordingly....I searched for HTTP POST but not getting how to call that particular method..thanks

Comment: There are no methods on HTTP level. POST operates with URL only, the rest is up to your server side. It is not SOAP request, you need to modify your server code in order to accept generic POST with binary data in the request body.