# How to do image processing on a big size bitmap without crashing

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I want to load a big size (about 10 MB) image and let user add some effects (such as Grayscale and so on). So, I loaded the bitmap using `inSampleSize` to show a preview to user:

```
public Bitmap load(Context context, int[] holderDimention, String image_url) throws Exception {
    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_url, bitmapOptions);

    int inSampleSize = 1;

    final int outWidth = bitmapOptions.outWidth;
    final int outHeight = bitmapOptions.outHeight;

    final int holderWidth = holderDimention[0];
    final int holderHeight = holderDimention[1];

    // Calculation inSampleSize
    if (outHeight > holderHeight || outWidth > holderWidth) {
        final int halfWidth = outWidth / 2;
        final int halfHeight = outHeight / 2;

        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > holderHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > holderWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decoding bitmap
    bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_url, bitmapOptions);
}
```

Finally,in background I want to apply effects on the original image without downsampling (it is necessary). So I used the following code inside a subclass of `AsyncTask`:

```
public Bitmap load(Context context, String image_url) throws IOException {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_url);
}
```

But I got an out of memory exception. How could I handle this problem?

Comment: You should add a `try{} catch (OutOfMemoryException e){}` in your code to avoid crash. This is a big issue with ALL android devices. Anrdoid applications have a maximum of 24MB RAM available so bitmap operations are hard to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it partially. Load only part of the image, process, save part. Check out [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html).

Related question: [Crop image without loading into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223062/crop-image-without-loading-into-memory)