# BitmapFactory.decodeFile causes outOfMemoryError

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory

BitmapFactory.decodeFile causes outOfMemoryError only when I choose the image from the phone gallery, not when I choose the image from taking the photo with the camera intent. I actually avoid using decodeFile when using the camera intent. Can I use that same approach when choosing from the gallery (getting data from the intent)? Here is my code for getting the image in both ways:

If image was chosen from the device' gallery:

```
if (requestCode == 1) 
              {
                  if (intent != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK) 
                  {
                  ImageHelper ih = new ImageHelper();
                  mProfilePicPath = ih.getSelectedImageFilePathFromGallery(this, intent);
                  Bitmap portraitPhoto = ih.getChosenImageFromGallery(mProfilePicPath);
                    try{
                        ih.saveImage("Profile pics", portraitPhoto, this);
```

ImageHelper.getChosenImageFromGallery:

```
public Bitmap getChosenImageFromGallery(String imagePath) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
        options.inSampleSize = DressingRoomActivity.calculateInSampleSize(options, 500, 500);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap portraitPhoto = ImageHelper.convertToPortraitOrientation(options, imagePath);
        return portraitPhoto;
    }
```

If image was chosen by taking photo using camera:

```
else if ((requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST)&& (resultcode == Activity.RESULT_OK)){
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                if (extras != null) {
                    ImageHelper ih = new ImageHelper();
                    mProfilePicPath = ih.getFilePathFromCameraPhoto(this, selectedImage);
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
                    try{
                    ih.saveImage("Profile pics", photo, this);
```

As you can see, to grab the image from the gallery and get the Bitmap from it, I have to create the Bitmap to be only 500 x 500 pixels with this code `options.inSampleSize = DressingRoomActivity.calculateInSampleSize(options, 500, 500);` Otherwise it causes an outOfMemoryError on the line `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);` Which is in the `ImageHelper.convertToPortraitOrientation(options, imagePath);` method. This means the user gets AS IS quality in their image from the camera, and 500px quality from their image in the gallery.

My questions: 1) Is there any way to not make my image quality 500px when choosing from gallery? Like avoid this line somehow: `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);` or some other way?

2) With the gallery I had to convert to portrait which is only a minor annoyance but why is that? It flips the photo sideways if I don't.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) is a complete tuto on how to [Display Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) from the official doc. I had the same problem as you. What i did was to read and understand all the lessons from the given page before returning back to my codes. Try that, you will get things clearer in your head.

**Edit**

Your app is crashing because you are running the `Bitmap.decode()` method in the main thread. Use another thread (with a simple `AsyncTask`) to do that.

As i said before, there is [a nice tuto on how to handle bitmap off UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

Comment: After reading that, I think most of those approaches are for performance. I'm just looking at not crashing the memory for now. I think the only fix there was making the image smaller which I am already doing :/ It said Caching can use more memory. It also suggested not using WeakReference. Not really sure what to do as I need an output image of same quality as input. It's a photo editor app.

Comment: see my edit. `I'm just looking at not crashing the memory for now` : you have to handle bitmaps nicely to avoid app crashing. That's why i provided the link above. Read the tutos, try to understand and come back for any question.

Comment: Thanks, however i'm fairly sure from research that asynctask is for making it load faster, and will not address the outofmemoryerror. It will take the same memory in the worker thread. I have just looked at other peoples similar questions and the answer is consistantly "make the image smaller". Unfortunately I think this is my only option

Comment: You put the bitmap decoding job in an `AsyncTask` to avoid potential long running I/O jobs (read file etc), not to save you from OOM (allocations).

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 possible solutions to overcome outOfMemory exception:

Solution 1: you should use weakReference variables like.

```
WeakReference<Bitmap> weakReferenceBitmap=new
             WeakReference<Bitmap>(bitmap);
```

GC clear weakReference variable more efficient as compare to other.

Solution2: you can use largeHeap property in your manifest to require more heap space then normal.

```
<application
        android:largeHeap="true">

</application>
```

I will not recommend you the 2nd solution, but it works :)

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks! largeHeap sounds like it might not be usable on low quality Android devices. Will WeakReference<Bitmap> work in this method if I edit it? `public static Bitmap createRotatedBitmap(Bitmap bm, float degree) {
     Bitmap bitmap = null;
     if (degree != 0) {
         Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
         matrix.preRotate(degree);
         bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                 bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
     }
     return bitmap;
 }`

Comment: WeakRefrence will work! But if you are doing too much decoding then you should use largeHeap option. Don't worry, app will work on low quality android devices as well.

Comment: Thanks :) This app is all about images. There is a lot of decoding. So I will use largeHeap. Should I also use WealReference<Bitmap>, in your opinion?

Comment: Yes, please use both, because largeHeap is only to get more heap then normal, But we should manage that heap efficiently.

Comment: Thanks. I will mark as the answer once I have confirmed it works, first I want to research WeakReference to ensure I use it correctly. At some point I must convert from WeakReference to a real Bitmap, yes?

Comment: no, you don't need to convert weakReference to real bitmap. Because when you call weakReference.get().. it will return the real bitmap. Weak Reference is like a box, you can put your object inside it. Please see documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html

Comment: @user3164083 Here is why you should NOT go with largeHeap as the first resort to OOM problems: [largeHeap pitfalls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application/11275704#11275704)

Comment: @Magnus Thanks. I have made the images 500px for now. It still looks ok, but not amazing. I don't kill off my activities when I go to a new activity. Am I supposed to to free up memory?