# How to prevent OutOfMemoryError in Android coding

Tags: android

I made HangMan Game which is random 200 activity and each activity has animation but I didn't know how to clear animation after level clear, bellow is error in my Google Developer Console, Anyone knew how to solve this problem?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:873)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2970)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:15697)
at kids.game.hangmanforkids.crab.update_HangMan_Picture(crab.java:913)
at kids.game.hangmanforkids.crab$13.onClick(crab.java:615)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you running any threads in parallel?

Comment: Dear Naveen Kuma, what do you mean by that sir?

Comment: That means Do you running any parralel execution at the time of error occurred..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  **android:largeHeap="true"** to increase heap size for your app in your menifest. Some devices have fixed amount of memory used by app say 64 MB per app. Or use scaling and caching to fix the memory used my application.
have look at these links 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

[How to increase heap size of an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application)