# Why not always declare large heap size

Tags: android, heap-memory

As android app's heap size is limited by device. Declare android:largeHeap="true" will increase heap size to decrease oom issue. It seems there are no disadvantage (for app). Why don't developer always set it as true and if so why this statement needs to be specially declared? Thanks.

Comment: See commonsware answer on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application

Comment: The answer only answers how to declare large heap size, but i want to know if it is possible to eliminate the declaration and replace with dynamic large heap size.