# Java Memory leak - OOM heap size

Tags: java, oracle, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, memory-profiling

My application ran fine all this time. We have a upadte by our operations team and i see that Oracle JDBC driver(11.2.0.3) was updated and the JDK was updated to 1.6.30.

I have been reading all blogs and have checked for any missed connections that were not closed, but none of these have solved my problem.
I see that the memory allocated once the methods run are not freed up once the processing is completed.

I have added finally blocks to all methods where i am querying

```
    } finally {
        try {
            if (results != null) {
                results.close();
                results = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { resources.logException(this.getClass().getName(), e);}
        try{
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
                statement = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { resources.logException(this.getClass().getName(), e); }
        try{
            if (connection != null) {
                resources.free(connection);
                connection.close(); 
                connection=null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { resources.logException(this.getClass().getName(), e); }
    }
```

My application runs fine for couple hours and then throws OutofMemory - Java Heap size.
I also ran core dump and heap dump - I analyzed the HPROF file - I see this as a suspect

5,832 instances of "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection", loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x96fe0a10" occupy 348,070,864 (67.53%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.WeakHashMap$Entry[]", loaded by ""

Please let me know if there is anything i am missing.

I also changed the -XMX to 1024 and it still no changes (was set at 256)

Comment: Have you noted a large heap in your manifest? Edit: [Relative question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application).

Comment: what happens if `resources.free()` throws an exception?

Comment: Also, is your code using WeakHashMap to track connections?  if so, you should show that code.

Comment: I am not using large heap in manifest.

Comment: What is holding on to the WeakHashMap?  What are you using to manage connection cache?