# dalvikvm-heap out of memory large size image

Tags: android, bitmapimage

I searched on the internet but didn't get a solution. 
How do I get a Bitmap of a Large size image(13 Mb) from the path of an image in the SD card or phone memory?

I use this:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```

and get an exception on this line

Thanks.

Comment: This has to do with the Java Heap Size.  Take a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11275719/3033053)

Comment: Additionally, make sure you dispose your bitmap after you're done using it (if you aren't doing so already)

Comment: the error came on first load means not a single time image loaded so i don't think it's because of not recycle bitmap

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's the java heap size.  The comment about disposing the bitmap was just a word of caution.  If you do not, it will lead to memory leaks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the Java Heap Size.

You can request a larger heap using the manifest on devices that are 2.3 or above.

See this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11275719/3033053) for more information.

Comment: there is a problem this solution works only Samsung s4 but not on s2 tell me ?

Comment: Impossible to tell you without more detail.  Could be the version of Android (this solution only works on 2.3 and above as mentioned in the original answer).  Another option is simply reducing the size of the bitmap that you are loading.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:largeHeap="true" for solve this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:largeHeap="true"
```