# Using SnapShotReadyCallback Method to get bitmap of my map fragment in android causing outofmemoryerror

Tags: android, maps, out-of-memory, snapshot

Here is my LogCat

08-08 11:30:20.866  12663-13312/com.example.sunny.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4466
    Process: com.example.sunny.myapplication, PID: 12663
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:928)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:901)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:868)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.a.b$3e99e895(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.s$5.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Answer (score 0):

maybe its size is too big for your app. Try to set `android:largeHeap="true"` on the `<application>` element in Android manifest to request a larger-than-normal heap size.

You can read more here: [How to increase heap size of an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application)