# Is it possible to consume more memory than the heap size on Android?

Tags: android, memory

I left my app running in the foreground on aSamsung Galaxy note 3 for 24 hours. I took a RAM snapshot in the beginning.

{"AvailableSystemRAM":1341,"AvailableAppRAM":10,"TotalAppRAM":49}

alter 12 hours:

{"AvailableSystemRAM":1265,"AvailableAppRAM":4,"TotalAppRAM":52}

after 24 hours the result is:

{"AvailableSystemRAM":992,"AvailableAppRAM":0,"TotalAppRAM":61}

Is it a sign of memory leak or other apps and services processing in the background? I presume that Android would throw an OutOfMemoryError if I used all the availableAppRam.

**UPDATE**

The answer is yes. Some native functions caused a minor memory leak that wasn't visible in Android Studio's memory monitor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase heap size of an android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application)

Comment: You got me wrong. I don't need to increase the heap, but I'm interested how it works really. Can I use more RAM than the heap limit, or that would throw an OutOfMemoryError? So can I leak 400MB of RAM on an Android device, or that is impossible by design.

Comment: I see. I was confused by the title.. Although I'm not sure what you could change it to in order to clear up the confusion. I actually just ran into an issue like this at work. We were getting `OutOfMemoryError` on certain devices after a gigantic mystery allocation. So, I guess anecdotally, you'll just get an OOM Exception at a certain level of consumption.

Comment: You should monitor the heap of you app, not the total heap of your device if you want to find out if you app has memory leaks.

Comment: It is true generally. But in this case I had a tiny memory leak in the native environment that led to unexpected application closes on the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html#compressToJpeg(android.graphics.Rect,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)) to convert my images. Later I found a report about this method here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36997431