# not able to find bugs in Log cat

Tags: android-studio, logcat

[image]

I'm not able to find bugs in `logcat` and it is throwing out of memory

Comment: u need to increase the heap size, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

It is **OOM problem** for Bitmap, I think you need to search for the reason for this problem. It is usually caused by the size of Bitmap which is to large I think.