# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while converting JSONArray to StringBuilder

Tags: android, arrays, string, out-of-memory

I am trying to write large JSONArray to string and then saved in sdcard. In this process getting OutOfMemory exception while converting JSONArray to string. The code will be given below. Please anyone say how to overcome this...

**Code:**

```
JSONArray loanSurvey = callbackObject.getJSONArray("bankloansurvey");
            try {
                String filename = "surveyfile.txt";
                File myFile = new File(surveyFolder, filename);
                if (!myFile.exists())
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos;
                StringBuilder surveyData = new StringBuilder(result.length());
                surveyData.append(loanSurvey.toString());            // here getting outofmemory error
                byte[] dataArray = surveyData.toString().getBytes();
```

**Error Report:**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
                                                                        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:132)
                                                                        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:124)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONStringer.string(JSONStringer.java:344)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:252)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:672)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:237)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONArray.writeTo(JSONArray.java:602)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:233)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:672)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:237)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONArray.writeTo(JSONArray.java:602)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:233)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:672)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:237)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONArray.writeTo(JSONArray.java:602)
                                                                        at org.json.JSONArray.toString(JSONArray.java:574)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application)

Comment: What is size of the JSON?

Comment: If out of memory than why not perform the operation in thread and increase heap size?!

Comment: it is nearly 7 mb @Mani

Comment: how to increase heap size @silverFoxA

Comment: Go to android manifest and add  **android:largeHeap="true"** within the application tag

Comment: @silverFoxA  thank u.... it works perfect......

Comment: I've experienced this issue when I convert the JSON into String. (over ~5MB) then we decide it to split the json into segment.

Comment: @Mani it solved my problem... thank u

Comment: @NarendraKumar please accept the answer

Comment: if this question is valid please upvote it...

Answer (score 0):

There may be two resons:

1. when memory leaks in your application.
2. Devices do not have enough memory when running your application.

Here can't increase the heap size dynamically but you can request to use more by using.

```
<application
..................
..................
android:largeHeap="true"/>
```

in the manifest.xml.

Answer (score -1):

If out of memory than perform the operation in thread and increase heap size.

To edit heapsize

Go to android manifest and add **android:largeHeap="true"** within the application tag

Comment: `Never request a large heap simply because you've run out of memory.` https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Comment: @GokhanArik Please suggest a better way to do it so that we make our program much more efficient

Comment: @Mani Thank you 

Comment: break your file into pieces. don't write all at once.

Comment: How about this case where I need to perform the operation for entire string!!

Comment: Please consider using POJO class that might solve your problem to some extent if the JSON string is too big