# How can fix OutOfMemoryError in rajawali3d when I open a big file (heap fragmentation)?

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango, rajawali

I have a problem with rajawali on google project tango tablet application.
I'm trying to open a different size / extension:
file.obj from blender -> 38MB
file.3ds from blender -> 38MB

I receive the error below, relative to OutOfMemory (heap fragmentation) 
How can I upload a file with this dimension or how can tune the model export with Blender?

Thanks
Onofrio

```
01-28 18:51:50.017 11738-11769/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 529
Process: com.projecttango.examples.java.modelcorrespondence, PID: 11738
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 54039108 byte allocation with 179088 free bytes
 at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
 at java.nio.MemoryBlock.allocate(MemoryBlock.java:125)
 at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:72)
 at org.rajawali3d.Geometry3D.setVertices(Geometry3D.java:741)
 at org.rajawali3d.Geometry3D.setVertices(Geometry3D.java:731)
 at org.rajawali3d.Geometry3D.setData(Geometry3D.java:450)
 at org.rajawali3d.Object3D.setData(Object3D.java:160)
 at org.rajawali3d.Object3D.setData(Object3D.java:153)
 at org.rajawali3d.loader.LoaderSTL.readBinary(LoaderSTL.java:263)
 at org.rajawali3d.loader.LoaderSTL.parse(LoaderSTL.java:92)
 at org.rajawali3d.loader.LoaderSTL.parse(LoaderSTL.java:67)
```

Comment: Could you attached some code on the model loading part? Is there any texture being loaded?

Comment: Did you try the android:largeHeap parameter in your Android manifest file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application