# How to increase heap size on Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, heap-memory, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am getting an OutOfMemoryError when I try to create a `String` larger than 4MB using `StringBuilder.append()`.

As far as I know, `StringBuilder` doesn't have any limitations regarding size and so doesn't `String`.

So I searched for "how to increase Android heap size" and as far as I could conclude from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598835/alternative-of-vmruntime-getruntime-setminimumheapsize-in-gingerbread), Gingerbread is the only version in which you have no way of dealing with the heap size, since for earlier versions you use the VMRuntime class and for newer versions `android:largeHeap="true"` on the Manifest.

Is that assumption correct? What do you do when you're in between VMRuntime and `android:largeHeap="true"`?

I used `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1048576 - Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1048576` to get "5.00 MB allocated of 42.00 MB available" on the device I'm using for tests (Android 2.3.6).

Comment: I'd call this an X Y Problem: You shouldn't be looking for a way to increase the memory. You should be looking for a way to fix that you're building 4MB Strings in memory.

Comment: @zapl Sometimes when dealing with legacy systems you have no choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that assumption correct?

I cannot say whether `VMRuntime` ever worked. `android:largeHeap` is definitely something for API Level 11+.

> What do you do when you're in between VMRuntime and android:largeHeap="true"?

Find a more memory-efficient way of building your 4MB `String`, such as by providing a large capacity to your `StringBuilder` constructor.

Or, find a way to implement whatever it is that you are doing without creating a contiguous 4MB `String`.

Comment: Interesting, @CommonsWare Mark! So you don't get to play with the heap when you're in Gingerbread, but it does grow in certain scenarios.
I used `StringBuilder`'s `ensureCapacity(8388608)` to ensure it would allocate 8MB to it. And sure enough, I got a "_dalvikvm-heap | Grow heap (frag case) to 33.268MB for 8388624-byte allocation_" message ... and the error is gone.

A contiguous large random `char` `String` is being used so less write operations are needed to create a file with maximum file size. Do you suggest any other wiser approaches?

Comment: @NickFanelli: " A contiguous large random char String is being used so less write operations are needed to create a file with maximum file size" -- in particular, because Dalvik does not have a compacting garbage collector, you are not fragmenting your heap quite so much. "Do you suggest any other wiser approaches?" -- other than avoiding the really big `String` in the first place (somehow), no..